# Combine 2 rows into 1 row - Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have a resultset as below,

```
id fname  lname
11 Tom   Jerry
11 Tom   Harry
```

Is there a way I could merge both the rows into 1 row, and lname value merged with comma seperated. Like below,

```
11 Tom   Jerry,Harry
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Stuff and some XML working. Edit: Not tested on sybase but give it a go and see

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (id int, fname varchar(20), lname varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #TestData 
VALUES
 (11,'Tom','Jerry')
,(11,'Tom','Harry')
```

Query

```
SELECT 
a.id
,a.fname
,STUFF((SELECT ',' + b.lname
        FROM #TestData b 
        WHERE b.id = a.id 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') lname
FROM #TestData a
GROUP BY a.id, a.fname
```

Result

```
id  fname   lname
11  Tom     Jerry,Harry
```

Comment: Is 'FOR XML PATH' available in Sybase?

Comment: unsure, i missed that part of the original question. this is a tried and tested method on sql server but I don't have access to a sybase dev system i'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the effort anyways. Also GROUP_CONCAT which does the same is not available in sybase. Sad!!

Comment: You could use SELECT LIST(name, ', ') FROM cities; for Sybase https://www.sqlines.com/sybase-asa-to-sql-server/list

Answer (score 0):

steps : (Pseudo code)

1 - get base table data in order by id,fname

2 - process each row in cursor and use below logic till id,fname values are    same once it gtes changed , control should come out of loop to insert new set of values(id,fname) appended by comma separated lastname

```
BEGIN
  SET @List = @List + ',' + Cast(@lname As varchar(10)) 
END
```